# Update columns by table trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 tables: Orders and Orders_Detail. Orders:id,amount,discount(0-100); all is number. Orders_detail: id,id_order,price,qty,str_sum(price*quantity*(1/discount/100)),idx(number of a row in order); all is number. What I need, if orders.discount is changed orders_detail.str_sum should recount.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CHANGE_DIS
 BEFORE 
 UPDATE OF DISCOUNT
 ON ORDERS
 REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW 
declare
    p_idx number;
    p_price number;
    p_qty number;
    cursor price_qty_idx is
    select price,qty,idx from orders_detail where id_order = :n.id;
begin
    open price_qty_idx;
    loop 
    fetch price_qty_idx into p_price,p_qty,p_idx;
        exit when price_qty_idx%notfound;
        update orders_detail set str_sum=p_price * p_qty * (1-:n.discount/100) where id_order = :n.id and idx = p_idx;
    end loop;
end;
```

Next I need, if orders_detail.str_sum changed(also if inserted or deleted new row, and changed price,qty,str_sum), orders.amount should recount. Do smth like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_BID
 BEFORE 
 INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF STR_SUM, QTY, PRICE
 ON ORDERS_DETAIL
 REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW 
declare
    p_amount number;
    p_discount number;
begin
    if inserting then
        select nvl(discount,0) into p_discount from orders where id = :n.id_order;
        :n.str_sum := :n.price * :n.qty * (1-p_discount/100);
        select nvl(sum(str_sum),0) into p_amount from orders_detail where id_order = :n.id_order;
        p_amount := p_amount + :n.str_sum;
        update orders set amount = p_amount where id = :n.id_order;
    elsif updating then
        select nvl(p_discount,0) into p_discount from orders where id = :n.id_order;
        :n.str_sum := :n.price * :n.qty * (1-p_discount/100);
        select nvl(amount,0) into p_amount from orders where id = :n.id_order;
        p_amount := p_amount - :o.str_sum + :n.str_sum;
        update orders set amount = p_amount - :o.str_sum + :n.str_sum where id = :n.id_order;
    elsif deleting then
        select amount-:o.str_sum into p_amount from orders where id = :o.id_order;
        update orders set amount = p_amount where id = :o.id_order;
    end if;
end;
```

[Exception that I had when update orders.discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rut8l.png)
Is it possible do it? Any ideas

Comment: everytime you update orders order detail gets update, which in turn again updates orders, you see how that is a problem, so you must approach your problem in a different way, where such ring updates will not happen

Comment: for example amount doesn't belong in orders, it is a calculated vaue that can begenerated at runtime, and is so redundant

Comment: @nbk Yes, it can be calculated at run-time (and maybe it should and a `VIEW` could be created) but there can also be performance reasons which might mean that the OP wants to pre-calculate the value (and they should ensure that they do actually need this and are not prematurely optimising). As for your first comment, the OP is restricting the triggers to only trigger on certain columns and there will not be a cycle of updates as the second trigger only changes `amount` and doesn't affect `discount` on the `orders` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AFTER UPDATE` for the `ORDERS` trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CHANGE_DIS
 AFTER UPDATE OF DISCOUNT ON ORDERS
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders_detail
  SET   str_sum = price * qty * (1-:NEW.discount/100)
  WHERE id_order = :NEW.id;
END;
/
```

and a compound trigger for `ORDERS_DETAIL` (and you do not need to trigger on changes to `str_sum`):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bid
FOR INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF QTY, PRICE ON ORDERS_DETAIL
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF ORDERS.ID%TYPE;
  ids ids_type := ids_type();
BEFORE EACH ROW
  IS
    v_discount ORDERS.DISCOUNT%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    IF NOT DELETING THEN
      SELECT discount
      INTO   v_discount
      FROM   orders
      WHERE  id = :NEW.id_order;

      :NEW.str_sum := :NEW.price * :NEW.qty * (1-v_discount/100);
    END IF; 

    IF :OLD.id_order IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.id_order NOT MEMBER OF ids THEN
      ids.EXTEND;
      ids(ids.COUNT) := :OLD.id_order;
    END IF;

    IF :NEW.id_order IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.id_order NOT MEMBER OF ids THEN
      ids.EXTEND;
      ids(ids.COUNT) := :NEW.id_order;
    END IF;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;  
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. ids.COUNT
      UPDATE orders
      SET   amount = (1 - discount/100) * (SELECT SUM(qty*price)
                                           FROM   orders_detail
                                           WHERE  id_order = ids(i))
      WHERE id = ids(i);
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fFuAE4I1)

Comment: thank u man, since which oracle version compound trigger works?

Comment: @mksdzt The code works in Oracle 11g [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AsEeYCf7). I have no idea what version they were introduced in.